# ASP.net references to DLLs

Tags: asp.net

I've got an ASP.net project with a folder containing some dll's.  I have referenced the DLL's from the folder.

I've modified one of the DLL's (Added a new class).  I get build errors saying that the new class does not exist.  When I add the reference the build errors go away in the Error List window.  However, When I build the project the errors come back again.

I've set up a test project and referenced the DLL's and can access the new class with no problems so I know the class exists in the dll.

Currently Tearing my hair out!!! Can anyone help?

EDIT: Forgot to mention I've also checked the refresh files and they seem to be pointing to the correct location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the order of build sequence. If some library is relied by another, it should be set in the dependency list.

Comment: how do I do that? where can i see dependancy list in a website project?

Comment: There are no dependancies on the DLL that I am trying to add

Comment: Ok, finally worked it out.  Turns out that there was another DLL that relied on another being in a certain directory.  Uuurgh!